# Combine arrays depending on checked boxes

Tags: php

I have a form with check boxes.

I want it so that when a check box is checked, it includes an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main" checked> Main/unsorted<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="art" value="art" checked> Art/literature/music<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="games" value="games" checked> Games/gaming<br />
```

If main is checked include the array 'main', if art is checked include the array 'art', etc.

I've tried, but I can't find a function that would work for this scenario.

Edit: I'm cheating a bit and am now doing it like so.

```
foreach($_GET as $get) {
    $end = array_merge($end, $$get);
}
```

Comment: _include_ the array? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Wrikken I have the array main, the array art, etc. and when the box is checked for it, I want them to join together like one array so I can randomly choose one result from all of the combined arrays.

Comment: Step back, we don't know your code: we post this form (I assume)? THere your have an array in php-code, what is it you want to do with said array? Merge it with another one you already have? Post some receiving code, input and desired output to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your information it sounds like you want to merge an array depending on which checkboxes have been ticked? Am I correct in assuming this?

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
<?php

$combinationArray = array();
$mainArray = array('item1','item2','item3');
$artArray = array('item4','item5','item6');
$gamesArray = array('item7','item8','item9');
if(isset($_POST['main']) && $_POST['main']=='main'){
    $combinationArray = array_merge($combinationArray,$mainArray);
}
if(isset($_POST['art']) && $_POST['art']=='art'){
    $combinationArray = array_merge($combinationArray,$artArray);
}
if(isset($_POST['games']) && $_POST['games']=='games'){
    $combinationArray = array_merge($combinationArray,$gamesArray);
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main" checked> Main/unsorted<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="art" value="art" checked> Art/literature/music<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="games" value="games" checked> Games/gaming<br />

    <button>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```